# Differene between Autoencoder Network and Fully Convolution Network

Tags: image, autoencoder

what is the main difference between **autoencoder networks** and **fully convolutional network**? 
Please help me understand the difference between architecture of these two networks?

Answer (score 1):

Autoencoders have at least one hidden fully connected layer which "is usually referred to as code, latent variables, or latent representation" [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder).
Actually, autoencoders do not have to be convolutional networks at all - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) only states that they are feed-forward non-recurrent networks.

On the other hand, Fully Convolutional Networks do not have any fully connected layers. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-Net) and [this paper by Cicek et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.06650.pdf) for more details (the paper has a nice visualization of the network).

So even when both an encoder and a decoder in an autoencoder network are CNNs, there is at least one fully-connected hidden layer in between them. Thus, autoencoder networks are not FCNs.

Answer (score 0):

1] **AutoEncoder :**

- Autoencodder is a dimensionality reduction technique
- It has two parts an encoder and decoder
- Enocder maps the raw data to a hidden representation (Latent Space Representation)
- Decoder maps the hidden representation back to raw data
- The network automatically learns this hidden representation and it turns out that this hidden representation are the most important feature of your data
- So The raw data goes as input to the encoder and it outputs the Latent Space Representation
- Now the output of the encoder is the input to the decoder which will try to regenerate the raw data
- Autoencoder is type of unsupervised learning
- Below is a diagram of Autoencoder that uses convolution layer in encoder network and deconvolution layer in decoder network

  [image]

2] **Convolution Network:**

- Convolution Network are used for images
- in convolution network set of filters are used to convolve
- The filters are shared across the data
- Which means that you data shares weights
- Each pixel value of your filter is a weight
- To know the convolution operation check out this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_zFhWdM4ic
- Every convolution layer does this convolution operation
- Convolutional networks are type of supervised learning
- Convolutional networks use Pooling operations for down sampling
- Below is diagram of convolution network[image]
- In the above diagram usually the classifier is a fully connected layer
- But it is not necessary to have fully connected layer as a classifier .. you can use other classifiers
- You can refer this for understanding difference between convolutional networks and MLP network: http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

3] **Fully Connected Layers:**

- These are simple layers with neurons
- Each neuron has a set of weights based on the input
- Below is the diagram of Fully connected layer

[image]